# how to use gets function in c++ code?

Tags: c++

In the main function of this code in the case 2 of switch case after entering the string program terminates!  What is the problem with the code?

```
/*this code is a implementation of bubble sort algorithm*/

#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<dos.h>

using namespace std;
int counter;
template <class T>//template created

class program//class which holds all the sorting functions
{
    public:
        T *v,x;
        int j,k,l,siz,flag;
        time_t t1,t2;
        char c;
    public:
        void sortlist()//fn to sort characters and numbers
        {
            cout<<endl<<"------->>INTERMEDIATE STEPS<<-------";
            for(k=1;k<=siz-1;k++)//sorting using a bubble sort
            {   flag=0;
                cout<<endl<<"PASS : "<<k<<endl;
                j=0;
                while(j<=siz-1-k)
                {
                    if(v[j]>v[j+1])//comparing two consecutive elements
                    {
                        x=v[j+1];
                        v[j+1]=v[j];
                        v[j]=x;
                        flag++;
                    }
                    for(l=0;l<siz;l++)
                    {
                        cout<<v[l]<<"  ";
                    }
                    cout<<endl;
                    j++;
                }
                cout<<"COMPARISONS:"<<(siz-k)<<endl;
                if(flag==0)
                {
                    cout<<endl<<"----->NO need to carry out more passes"<<endl<<"List is already sorted"<<endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            }


        void stringsort()//fn to sort the strings
        {

            T a[90][20],b[1][20];
            cout<<"enter the size of list:";
            cin>>siz;
            cout<<"enter the list:";
            cin.ignore();
            for(j=0;j<siz;j++)
            {
                gets(a[j]);
            }
            cout<<endl<<"------->>INTERMEDIATE STEPS<<-------";
            for(k=1;k<=siz-1;k++)//sorting using bubble sort
            {
                flag=0;
                cout<<endl<<"PASS : "<<k<<endl;
                j=0;
                while(j<siz-k)
                {
                    x=strcmp(a[j],a[j+1]);//comparing two consecutive string
                    if(x>0)
                    {
                        strcpy(b[1],a[j+1]);
                        strcpy(a[j+1],a[j]);
                        strcpy(a[j],b[1]);
                        flag++;
                    }
                     for(l=0;l<siz;l++)
                {
                    cout<<a[l]<<"       ";
                }
                cout<<endl;
                    j++;
                }
                cout<<endl<<"COMPARISON:"<<(siz-k)<<endl;
                if(flag==0)
                {
                    cout<<endl<<"No need to carry out more passes"<<endl<<"List is already Sorted"<<endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            cout<<"SORTED LIST:"<<endl;
            for(j=0;j<siz;j++)
            {
                cout<<endl<<a[j]<<endl;
            }
        }
};
int main()//main fn
{
    int x;
    char c;
    do
    {
        program <char> p1;
        program <int> p2;
        cout<<endl<<"To sort a list of NUMBERS enter -> 1"<<endl<<endl<<"To sort string of CHARACTERS enter -> 2"<<endl<<endl<<"To sort a list OF STRINGS and DOUBLE_STRINGS enter -> 3";
        cout<<endl<<endl<<"Enter either 1 OR 2 OR 3:";
        cin>>x;
        switch(x)
        {
       case 1://to sort list of numbers
            {
                cout<<endl<<"enter the size of list: ";
                cin>>p2.siz;
                cout<<"enter the list: "<<endl;
                p2.v=new int[p2.siz];
                for(p2.l=0;p2.l<=p2.siz-1;p2.l++)
                {
                    cin>>p2.v[p2.l];
                }
                    p2.sortlist();//sort and search in numbers
                cout<<endl<<"SORTED LIST:"<<endl;//sorted list after the bubble sort
                for(x=0;x<=(p2.siz)-1;x++)
                {
                    cout<<p2.v[x]<<endl;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 2://to sort string of character
            {
                    cout<<"enter the string of characters:";
                    cin.ignore()
                    gets(p1.v);
                    p1.siz=strlen(p1.v);
                    p1.sortlist();//sort in characters
                    cout<<endl<<"SORTED STRING:"<<p1.v;
            }
            break;
                case 3://to sort list of strings
                {
                        p1.stringsort();//sort list of string
                }
                break;
            default:
            cout<<"INVALID_CHOICE"<<endl<<endl;
        }
        cout<<endl<<"do u want to enter another list?y/n";
        cin>>c;
    }
    while(c=='y');
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that code is just a mess.   gets() is used for reading a string of chars, and you're attempting to use it to read an array of ints (depending on your template specialisation).    It can't do that.     gets() itself is deprecated from the latest C standard because it is unsafe, even if used as intended.

Comment: Don't. `gets` is inherently unsafe. It was removed from C by the 2011 standard. Find some other way to read input.

Comment: You call `gets(a[j])`. `gets` requires a `char*` argument. `a[j]` is of type `char*` only if your template is instantiated with type `char`. You instantiate it both with type `char` and with type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`gets` requires that you pass a pointer to enough storage space to hold the string that gets read. Your program passes an uninitialized pointer.

You're not really allowed to do anything with uninitialized values, so in theory your program can crash before it even enters the `gets` function.

Since the user can pass any amount of data to `gets` and your program would be responsible for storing it, the function is deprecated. It doesn't even exist any more in the C++ standard library as `std::gets` since 2011, although `::gets` will probably always be available in POSIX. The short answer is, "don't."

You might consider `std::string` and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead.